# How often do the User Reputation Leagues weekly stats get updated?

Tags: support, reputation-leagues

The MSE [User Reputation Leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/4/week/meta) for "week" currently shows:

> Apr 12, 2015 - Apr 12, 2015

It's not still Sunday (April 12th) for any timezones.
It's been Apr 13th for 6 hours even for UTC-12.

So does the "week" leagues only update and include stats for a full day, not part days?
e.g. at 00:00 UTC it will update and then show "Apr 12 - Apr 13".

Or, if it's updated more regularly, then the page's date range is inaccurate.

Comment: Sounds more like a bug, but not sure. :/

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yeah that's why I asked. It could simply be stats for a full days only, or otherwise wrong dates. Given the valid choice, "support" is less intrusive than "bug", and can change to bug easily

Comment: Yeah, but bugs get the team's attention faster. :)

Comment: True @ShadowWizard but it's not exactly a site breaker ;)

Comment: @PythonMaster If you read the comments, my not putting "bug" was intentional :) We don't know if this is a bug or if stats are simply updated at the end of the day. We'll know in a few hours without needed to spam the bug tag's attention

Comment: lol, I got the notification since Mr. Python deleted his comment before you submitted yours... ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so it's now 00:43 UTC (*Stack time*), and the MSE [User Reputation Leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/4/week/meta) for "week" now shows:

> Apr 12, 2015 - Apr 13, 2015

So I'm going to assume these stats are only calculated based on full days, and this is not a bug.

Answer (score 2):

According to my utterly destroyed MSO [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281683/leaderboards-not-updating), the accepted answer says that:

> The leaderboards only update once a day. Based on the following MSE answer, this happens at UTC 00:00:

So the leaderboards only update once every day, according to UTC time. If you visit the answer, it says that the information comes from a Meta Stack Exchange answer, which means it is applied to all sites.

Comment: ah thanks. Tho, that's for SO. All site's are *probably* the same, but maybe not for *reasons* (ie less traffic intensive sites might have had more frequent updates)